# How to link remote CSS to React component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-design

I am trying to create a simple component in React where I am trying to use Google's MDL from here https://getmdl.io/started/index.html , so as they state I need to link the CSS from their server , I would like to know where should i do this. I tried it adding it to main index.html and refer to style in component but seems like its not being used.
What should be the proper way to do this ?
I am a novice at React stuff.

Component code

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
       <div>
           <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
                   New button
           </button>
       </div>

      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

This is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<html lang = "en">

   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>React App</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "app"></div>
      <script src = "index.js"></script>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should be able to link it in your index.html, how did you refer to the style in the component?

Comment: @CésarLandesa exactly thanks that worked

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `className` instead of `class` to refer to css classes in React because `class` is a reserved word in ES6 and with JSX you are writing Javascript and not HTML. For example:

```
<button className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
    New button
 </button>
```